# custom cookie for ldap attribute in openam

Tags: openam

I am trying to generate a http cookie for successful user login in openam. The cookie is expected to be populated with a ldap attribute name 'commerce' which is a boolean attribute.

In order to achieve this I have done settings under -- access control --top level realm --agent -- configured policy agent --Profile Attributes Processing

Over here I have created a map with key as commerce and value of commerce, now ideally after a successful login it should generate a cookie with name --HTTP_COMMERCE with value of attribute, but this is not working as expected.

but when I made entry in Response Attributes Processing section as well for the commerce attribute,it started working

Can anyone let me know the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

If the attribute is not configured in the 'user attributes' section of the data store OpenAM can not populate it.

Check IdRepo debug log on OpenAM side (in message level) it will tell if OpenAM can retrieve the attribute.